# ExtJS 4 - MessageBox Prompt change input field type to password

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Good day. I am creating a web application which displays a Message Box from time to time. I have a message box that asks the user for a password and I want that field type to be password. So far I've tried several things but none of them seem to work, they still show the text as plain text and not as dots or asterisks.

Here's my code:

```
var mb = Ext.MessageBox.prompt({
    title: 'Enter Override Password.',
    msg: 'Please Enter the Override Password to Reprint:',
    password: true, //this does not work
    width: 300,
    height: 125,
    multiline: 1,
    inputType: 'password', //this does not work
    value: '',
    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNO,
    fn: myCallback,
    cls: 'msgbox',
    baseCls: 'msgbox',
    icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING
});
mb.textField.inputType = 'password'; //this does not work
```

Does anyone know how to specify the input field as password type? It seems that ExtJS 4.2 does not support it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I tried and it's worked thus far. The only problem I have now is styling and that's for another question.

```
var myMsgBox = new Ext.window.MessageBox({
    cls: 'msgbox',
    bodyCls: 'popWindow'
});
myMsgBox.textField.inputType = 'password';
myMsgBox.textField.width = 240;
myMsgBox.textField.center();
myMsgBox.prompt(title, msg, myCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that goes a little bit beyond the scope of what the `Ext.MessageBox` was designed for. In looking at the source code the only things that passed into the input are the value, and height if the multiline is set.

What you could do instead, is to create your own component that extends `Ext.Window` and sets modal to true. This allows you to customize the window as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Ext.MessageBox.prompt try with creating a custom window that extends Ext.Window, pop up when clicked on the button and sets modal to true and align to center.